# Batch File Echo a line contains % to a Text File

Tags: file, batch-file, command, dos, prompt

I'm adding the following line to a Batch file using:

```
ECHO enter.php?login=%s&pass=%s >>textfile.txt
```

the Output is coming as

```
enter.php?login=s
```

This is my first Batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double the `%` - Normally `^` escapes awkward characters like `>` so to have them reproduced literally, you'd use `^>`. `%` is different - you need `%%` for each `%` you want to "print"

Comment: Thanks I used %%s it worked out but seems the &pass=%s isn't going into the line, any tip I can use?

Comment: I tried it before asking about it :) still not working. **&pass=%s** is the only thing that isn't showing in the file.

Comment: Thank you, I added another Echo after the Echo line directly 

e.g. **Echo link/ Echo login=%s&pass=%s** it worked perfectly. thank you Peter :)

Comment: Sorry for that, it added the word ECHO into the line, but the line appeared correctly, it worked this way: **^enter.php?login.....**